# wordpress adding menu overlay on image hover

Tags: wordpress, menu, hover, overlay

Hey everyone I normally build sites in laravel but I have a client wanting a wordpress site and so I have been learning about wordpress and would like some guidance on how to add a menu that would appear when a user hovers over an image.

A perfect example can be found on the home page of starwell.cc where a clickable menu shows when you hover over an image. Is this possible in wordpress?

Any help is appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This would be accomplished with CSS and HTML, with a bit of custom WordPress.

- Are you building a theme from scratch, or are you customizing an existing one?
- Have you looked for an answer within plugins?

It would take a closer look, but my guess is that it's achievable by custom coding it into the theme and then using CSS and HTML

Comment: Thank you! I should of specified. I am using the divi theme as well as the divi visual builder. I did try to look into plugins and saw imagehover plugin but cant seem to get the effect I am ultimately desiring.

Comment: @rapid3642 - you may require a custom built plugin. If you customize the theme yourself, you will need to create a child theme, or else you will find huge headaches. 

Reach out if you need more help, my friend.